# What genre is the Terraria Soundtrack?

Tags: identify-this-genre, videogame-soundtrack

The [Terraria soundtrack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsSWqVCSaqs) is probably one of, if not my favorite video game soundtrack of all time, and I'd love to hear more music like it, but I'm having a hard time placing under a genre.

Is it ambient? Electronica? Chiptune? Something else? I can't figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: Per the [Terrraria wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Music), all the music was composed by [Scott Lloyd Shelly of Resonance Array](http://www.resonancearray.com/).  You could contact him to ask.  To my ears, it is clearly electronica, but also aiming at times for a Chiptune sound to give a retro game feel

Answer (score 2):

If I had to pick (which, like you said, is extremely hard), I would personally consider Terraria's soundtrack to be electronic orchestral music. When you listen to a lot of the sounds in the music (especially the boss themes), you will start to notice a lot of crossovers between the two genres. I wouldn't say chiptune however, because the way chiptunes are made is through very specific techniques, usually faithful to the console or PC of orgin e.g, NES, famicom, sega genesis, etc. The music found within Terraria most definitely could not be produced with the limitations of chiptunes, therefore eliminating chiptune from your options. Ambient could certainly be used to describe many the themes such as Overworld Night, Eerie, and Ocean, but on a lot of the more hectic themes like, Underground Crimson, Lunar Towers, and Boss 2, it would be out of the question to consider them "ambient." I would stick to something along the lines of electronic orchestral music. You should go to [Terraria Soundtrack | Re-Logic](https://re-logic.bandcamp.com/album/terraria-soundtrack) and listen to the various different themes that I listed to decide for yourself whether you agree with my opinion or not (A lot of the themes start slow, so it might be best to skip around within each song.)

I hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

While [Adrian's answer](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/5450/3431) is true, if you are asking specifically for the some of the boss music, I would definitely place some of the music in the same categories as the works of ['Infected Mushroom'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infected_Mushroom), i.e psychedelic, glitch, experimental, electronic rock